# Why Do I Have to Pick an OS to Generate Dockerfile from VS2017?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I was reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker#use-docker-tools-in-visual-studio-2017) on adding a Dockerfile from VS2017. When I click `Add Docker Support` I get a prompt `Target OS:`.

My understanding is that the whole point of Docker is that it doesn't really care on what system it is. So why the target OS prompt?

Edit: My understanding was that if a target OS kernel image is pulled down, then this can sit on top of any OS. This would increase the image size, but work on any OS. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are not distinct from the host operating system. When you choose a "Target OS", what you are selecting is the "host" OS for the container. Selecting Windows allows you to run software in your container that expects to be supported by a Windows Kernel and APIs. The software in a Linux container expects the support of the underlying Linux kernel and APIs.

Comment: So, would the need for this "choice" be eliminated if I were to pull down a base OS kernel image inside the image definition?

Comment: Pulling the kernel image into the container would not help. The container host infrastructure would not know about it nor start it when you started the container. If your use case requires a specific, versioned kernel to execute then what you want is a virtual machine not a container.